# Logarithm function of an arbitrary integer base in C

Tags: c, logarithm

Is there a function or any other way to calculate in C the logarithm of base `x`, where `x` is an integer variable of my program?

Comment: Anything wrong with `log(n)/log(x)`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

C doesn't provide functions to compute logarithms of any bases other than `e` or `10`.

So just use math:

```
logarithm of x base b = log(x)/log(b)
```

---

If you'll be doing the logarithms over the same base repeatedly, you can precompute `1/log(b)`.
I wouldn't rely on the compiler being able to do this optimization for you.